# Unable to install Swift in Ubuntu

Tags: swift, ubuntu-15.10

Hi I am trying to install Swift on Ubuntu (Ubuntu 15.10). I followed the guide of Apple at [swift.org](http://swift.org).  But after executing all the steps when I execute following command

```
swift --version
```

It returns error saying

```
harshit@harshit-Linux:~/swift/usr/bin$ swift --versionThe program 'swift' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-swiftclient
 * python3-swiftclient
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I used

```
export PATH=/home/harshit/swift/usr/bin/swift:"${PATH}"
```

Here is my directory path
http://pastebin.com/Z1aNiDQM

Kindly help me to complete installation.

Comment: It should not be `export PATH=/home/harshit/swift/usr/bin/swift:"${PATH}"`, it should be `export PATH=/home/harshit/swift/usr/bin:"${PATH}"`

Comment: @EricD.  It works. Thanks , Please add above comment as answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring your path like this:

```
export PATH=/home/harshit/swift/usr/bin/swift:"${PATH}"
```

but it's wrong because it includes the swift executable itself in the path.

It should be like this instead:

```
export PATH=/home/harshit/swift/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you did not add swift to your path.  Do you have the direct path to where it is installed?   You could try `/usr/whereever/bin/swift`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Checking that. will reply you soon.

Comment: Sorry for dumbness but, i executed following command                          export PATH=/home/harshit/swift/usr/bin/swift:"${PATH}"

Comment: No it doesn't , it says " bash: /usr/bin/swift: No such file or directory

Comment: @EricD. Yes in that case my above path is correct, I made a folder (named "swift") in "harshit" directory and pasted the extracted tar file in it.

Comment: File permissions off maybe?  Could you post your directory tree to the initial post so we can see more information